# Problems using 2 video tags in Chrome playing the same video

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

Context:

Making an advanced video-player using web components technology (polymer-project.org) I have found some problems when I tried to include 2 instances of the video-player playing the same video resource. Analyzing the problem I have realized that it has nothing to do with polymer but with the HTML5 video tag only on Chrome browser.

Problem:

The source of my test html page contains essentially the following code:

```
<video id="video1" width="100%" controls>
   <source src="/test/resources/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
...
<video id="video2" width="100%" controls>
   <source src="/test/resources/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
```

The effects of the anomalous behavior can be outlined as:

1. The second video does not show the first frame (a black player is shown instead)
2. Trying to play the second video player it does not work
3. The first video player works as expected
4. After pausing the first video, the second one appears on the player
5. Now the playing command on step 2 seems to respond and start suddenly the second player

Summing up, it is impossible to play both videos simultaneously. This only happens on chrome (neither on Safari nor Firefox) and when the video resource is the same one.

Question:

Does anybody have a suggestion about how can I proceed in order to fix the problem with chrome?

Comment: The `id` attribute of an HTML element should be unique. Your video players have the same `id`. This may or may not be the issue. Either way, please try changing the id's and then update your post/code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I have tried to make the change that you propose but the result is the same (now it is changed in the code of the question). Nevertheless, within the context of web components, the video tag is automatically generated from the template so it could not be possible to create a different id for each video. This id crashing is what `shadow-dom` technology of web components resolves successfully.

Comment: You could always Iframe the second video.

Comment: Thanks Diodeus but as I mention to the Daniel comment, both tag snippets are actually generated automatically by a template in my web component tag so any solution generating different snippets for each video instance are technologically not possible.